# couldn't get the object which I am posting using http post method in MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, express, post, mongoose, mean-stack

My code is(server.js) :

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var customerr = require('./customer')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/customers');

app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/customers', function (req,res){
  console.log("POST: ");
  console.log(req.body);
  var custom = new customerr({
    name : req.body.name,
    mobile : req.body.mobile,
    phone : req.body.phone,
    address :req.body.address,
    dob : req.body.dob,
    email : req.body.email});

    custom.save(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(custom);                     // doubt in this line
      console.log("created");
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
  return res.send(custom);
});
```

Mongoose schema(I don't think thats there is any error in it.) (customer.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  

var customerSchema = new Schema({  
    Name: { type: String }, 
    Mobile:  { type: String },  
    Number: { type: String },
    Address: { type: String },
    DOB: { type: String },
    Email:{ type: String }
});
var customerr = mongoose.model('customerr', customerSchema);  
module.exports =customerr;
```

My controller part :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");

var refresh = function() {
  $http.get('/customers').success(function(response) {
    console.log("I got the data I requested");
    //console.log(response);
    $scope.customers = response;
    $scope.customer = "";
  });
};

refresh();

$scope.addCustomer = function() {
  console.log($scope.customer);
  $http.post('/customers', $scope.customer).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);                
    refresh();
  });
};
```

doubt : In app.post() the output shown is given below :(POST is printed, req.body gets printed, but when I console.log(custom) only object id is printed nothing else, as if the req.body is not saving in custom object)

```
POST: 
{ name: 'ds',
  mobile: 'adas',
  phone: 'dasd',
  address: 'asd',
  dob: 'asdas',
  email: 'das' }
{ __v: 0, _id: 58bb591a7cdbe0b534000001 }
created
```

Comment: What happens when you do a res.json(custom) instead of res.send(custom), we may get more details.

Comment: same as above. nothing else.

Comment: the only problem is, after running the custom.save, I am only getting 
{ __v: 0, _id: 58bb591a7cdbe0b534000001 }   as the output. 
The  req.body part is not getting saved in custom object.

Comment: It certainly seems as though the other items aren't present, console log something like req.body.email + ' ' + req.body.name instead of your 'created' message, lets see if it says 'undefined'

Comment: yeah u r correct. In my mongoDB also, only the fields _id and _v are showing, none of the req.body part is getting saved into it.

Comment: I suggest you test if everything is working using just a simple form, after that then integrate angular, unless if you can find where the problem is coming from.

Comment: u just tell me one thing. How to save that req.body content in my custom object, thats it.

Comment: I am cooking a solution right now, but I won't be using angular, just a simple ejs form to test everything.

Comment: if u need any more part of code, just let me know.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: yes. the problem is in my app.post. I have used Capital letters in mongoose model, but used small letters in app.post. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Did setting the urlencoding extend property help as well?

Comment: I didn't tried using that.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the error was, don't worry all your code is fine. Add this above the app.use(bodyParser.json())     line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
});
```

It worked after I added that, cheers.